# Add enabledBorder color in date_time_picker package field in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

How to Add enabledBorder color in date_time_picker package field in flutter?
`

```
DateTimePicker(
  type: DateTimePickerType.dateTimeSeparate,
  dateMask: 'd MMM, yyyy',
  cursorColor: Colors.cyan,
  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
  icon: const Icon(Icons.event,color: Colors.indigo,),
  dateLabelText: 'Start Date',
  timeLabelText: 'Start Hour',
  selectableDayPredicate: (date) {
    // Disable weekend days to select from the calendar
    if (date.weekday == 6 || date.weekday == 7) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
  onChanged: (val) => print(val),
  validator: (val) {
    return null;
  },
  onSaved: (val) => print(val),
),
```

`
Add enabledBorder color in date_time_picker package field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add [`InputDecoration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html):

```
 DateTimePicker(
            type: DateTimePickerType.dateTimeSeparate,
            dateMask: 'd MMM, yyyy',
            cursorColor: Colors.cyan,
            firstDate: DateTime(2000),
            lastDate: DateTime(2100),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.event,
              color: Colors.indigo,
            ),
            dateLabelText: 'Start Date',
            timeLabelText: 'Start Hour',
            selectableDayPredicate: (date) {
              // Disable weekend days to select from the calendar
              if (date.weekday == 6 || date.weekday == 7) {
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            },
            onChanged: (val) => print(val),
            validator: (val) {
              return null;
            },
            onSaved: (val) => print(val),
            decoration: const InputDecoration( 
             prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.event,
                color: Colors.indigo,
              ),
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Result-> [image]